# Inserting a Hyperlink in Userform VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created a welcome note in excel using userform, which is shown everytime for 6 seconds whenever i open the workbook. I have inserted a hyperlink on that userform. But that hyperlink is not working.
i had used the following code in that label..

```
Private Sub Label2_Click()

    Link = "https://www.healthindiatpa.com/"

    On Error GoTo NoCanDo

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link, NewWindow:=True

    Unload Me

    Exit Sub

NoCanDo:

    MsgBox "Cannot open " & Link

End Sub
```

But it is not working. Whenever i click on that label or hyperlink when the workbook is opening, the website is not opening. The hyperlink is not working.
[Userform image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifqKD.jpg)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? 
Executes fine here.

Comment: The Hyperlink doesn't work..whenever i click the hyperlink, the website is not getting opened.

Comment: Have you tried executing using F8, to see if the event above even gets fired? Do you get the MsgBox saying "Cannot open https...."?

Comment: I have tried..the userform is executing..but when i click on the hyperlink on that userform..nothing is happening.

Comment: Then your link is not in Label2. Find out which label it is by clicking on the label and check the `Name` in the Properties window. Next alter the line `Private Sub Label2_Click()` to say `Private Sub LabelName_Click()`, so you hook in to the click event of the correct label. Alternatively, while in the editor of the userform, double click the link and paste the code in the newly generated `sub`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: My link is in Label 2..i have checked it in properties. Actually my userform is welcome note which is visible only for 6 seconds whenever i open that workbook. On that userform the hyperlink has been placed. And i don't know why my code is not working.

Comment: Can you provide a full code example (userform code + the way it's displayed + the timer to hide it after the 6 seconds?) The other option is that stuff is still running in the background. If you use some timer/ticker, you might want to add a line `DoEvents` in each loop there. VBA is single thread and synchronous execution after all.

Comment: Private Sub Label2_Click()
Link = "https://www.healthindiatpa.com/"
    On Error GoTo NoCanDo
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link, NewWindow:=True
    Unload Me
    Exit Sub
NoCanDo:
    MsgBox "Cannot open " & Link
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Loading Data..."
    UserForm1.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Please make sure Database file is open..."
    UserForm1.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Opening..."
    UserForm1.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    HideTitleBar Me
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: Sub HideTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lngWindow As Long
    Dim lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub

Comment: Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Public Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                       Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                       ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                       Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                       ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                       ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Comment: Public Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                       Lib "user32" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                       Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                       ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Comment: Please Edit your question to include all this code - The comment section is not intended for this. Also: See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in this snippet:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Loading Data..."
UserForm1.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Please make sure Database file is open..."
UserForm1.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Opening..."
UserForm1.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

The application is just waiting (so not accepting input whatsoever). That's why your event doesn't trigger, since after the wait it immediately continues with the next line (which is the label change and repaint).

You can fix it by altering this routine as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
DoEvents 'Allow for the label click to trigger!!!
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Loading Data..."
UserForm1.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
DoEvents 'Allow for the label click to trigger!!!
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Please make sure Database file is open..."
UserForm1.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
DoEvents 'Allow for the label click to trigger!!!
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Opening..."
UserForm1.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
DoEvents 'Allow for the label click to trigger!!!
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

It's not very clean, but this way you'll enter the Event code and fix your problem without other alterations.

**Edit:** 
This answer tells you how to capture the event and make it work, which is what the question was. Issues with the `FollowHyperlink` is a second thing: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-followhyperlink-method-excel) says the method will "open the appropriate program" based on the target you pass.

Since the code is correct **and** the event fires, this is most likely a completely **different issue** that has nothing to do with the VBA / your question.

On my machine (W7 + Excel 2016) the code executes perfectly and the click on the link works, consistently.

Comment: You're welcome mate. Also - If you could put your additional code in your Question and remove the code comments, that'd be great. Otherwise I'll flag this one for moderation.

Comment: One more problem mate..sometimes the link is opening but sometimes message box is getting popped up with Cannot open website....what to do

Comment: It is working only when i'm checking in vba editor...but in real time means while opening workbook it is not working.

Comment: Ask a new question - and troubleshoot your Browser, your Internet Connection and check availability of the URL. The code to open it is correct.

Comment: I have tried all of the above..everything is fine..it is showing Run time error 91. Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: I think it is not getting which application to open

Comment: Have you tried removing the error handling and see how it crashes? Based on your question (why doesn't the event work) I gave the answer. It works consistently here, so what you're facing is another issue that doesn't have anything to do with the question you asked.

Comment: I have removed the error handling, after that it has started showing..Run time error 91.

Comment: Are you sure you have an `ActiveWorkbook` set at the moment it executes?  Since you hide the active window, show the UserForm and the show the window that holds `ThisWorkbook`. Runtime 91 is object not set, which might be the case since `ActiveWorkbook`'s Window is hidden completely. Have you tried with `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink`?

Comment: Thank you Rik..for you time and support.